# Org-mode blank line at the end of tree

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to make blank lines at the end of tree part of that tree? So I can heave two headings like this:

```
* Heading1
* Heading2
```

without space between them, but when Heading1 is expanded there is a blank line at the end that does not propagate upwards. Like this:

```
* Heading1

  * Subheading1
  * Subheading2

* Heading2
```

It find it visually pleasing to have a blank line between Subheading2 and Heading2 but when Heading1 is collapsed I do not want to have a blank line between Heading1 and Heading2 ( I use org-indent-mode).

Currently I can have only the version without blank line at the end and without blank line between Heading1 and Heading2:

```
* Heading1

  * Subheading1
  * Subheading2
* Heading2
```

or version with blank line at the end of expanded Heading1 BUT that blank line propagates upwards and it appears between Heading1 and Heading2:

```
* Heading1

* Heading2
```

Comment: What you are saying should not be happening with the default value of `org-cycle-separator-lines` = 2. Have you set that to 1 in your config?

Comment: No, I have it set to 2.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://asciinema.org/a/2i8689s32tfv4mijjs5l9fisf) what you get in an emacs -Q session? I am running org built from the latest commit on its master branch.

Comment: Well, on that video it can be clearly seen in 0:51 that if you press TAB on heading for the first time, you get subheadings WITHOUT blank line at the end which is what I am trying to solve because very often I dont want to expand all the way down but only to see subheadings.

Comment: Sorry, there was some confusion at my end as I had initially copied your example and so I had white space preceeding the sub headings `* Subheading1` ... It's now clear that you need to see that white space in the `CONTENTS` view.

Comment: Yes, thats what I would like.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have an answer. If you set `org-cycle-separator-lines` to 1, you can get what you want in the `CONTENTS` view, but then you get that empty line displayed in `OVERVIEW` too.

Comment: Well I can just use 2 blank lines for that, without setting org-cycle-separator-lines to 1 but I am surprised that nobody was ever dealing with it (or maybe I just cannot find anything)

Comment: Yes, I for one never worried about this. You probably might need to request this behavior on the org-mode mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

**It does *not* look like there is an easy/built-in way to customize this behavior.**

The function `org-cycle-show-empty-lines` in `org.el` appears to be responsible for displaying whitespace between headings. (`org-cycle-show-empty-lines` is the only place in `org.el` where `org-cycle-separator-lines` is used).

This function appears to operate as follows:

- use `org-cycle-separator-lines` to build a regex
- use the regex to find any places that should cause 1 or more lines of whitespace to be displayed between headings
- display whitespace in the desired places

In other words, the function is pretty much hardcoded to act as described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/3c4xdk/spacing_between_items_when_trees_are_folded/cssojh4/).

**I found a few posts which modify similar folding behavior**

I'm afraid that I don't know enough elisp to provide an appropriate function definition yet. But I found a few other posts which have definitions for similar behavior -- that could at least contribute a starting point for a solution.

- [Hide tags in outline view](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32039/18678). The solution appears to be a function which you'd run in `org-cycle-hook`. The docstring for `org-cycle-show-empty-lines` mentions that hook

  > Show empty lines above all visible headlines. The region to be covered
  >   depends on STATE when called through `org-cycle-hook'.

  so it may be possible to get the desired behavior in `org-cycle-show-empty-lines` by mucking with STATE in `org-cycle-hook`.
- [Completely hide the PROPERTIES drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492723). The solution appears to be a complete rewrite of `org-cycle-hide-drawers`, a pre-existing function in `org.el`. In your case, this approach would involve a rewrite of `org-cycle-separator-lines`.

**Org mode version info:** 
Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /usr/local/Cellar/emacs-mac/emacs-25.2-z-mac-6.6/share/emacs/25.2/lisp/org/)