# Org-mode hide tags in outline view

Tags: org-mode, code-folding, org-tags

Can anyone think of a way to hide org-mode tags, perhaps something along the lines of this solution to [completely hide the properties drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478260/completely-hide-the-properties-drawer-in-org-mode)?

I would love to hide tags but still have them searchable and be able to make them visible through cycling.

Ideas?

Comment: I can think of two options off the top of my head:  (1) attach a function to the `org-agenda-finalize-hook` that goes through the near final product and redacts it using a regexp `\\(:[[:alnum:]_@#%:]+:\\)`; or, (2), modify `org-agenda-format-item` to structure the data before it gets inserted into the buffer.  No one, except me, likes to modify the source . . . so option two only applies to the very brave or stubborn souls.  I don't know of any adverse consequences to either approach off the top of my head, but it may behoove you to wait for someone like .. [insert name if I can think of it].

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping to find a solution that works in the plain org-mode buffer (the outline view, not the agenda view)... maybe I'm not referring to this correctly?

Comment: Ah, that makes a big difference then . . .  thank you for the clarification.

Comment: One idea would be to modify the whopper of `org-set-font-lock-defaults`, somewhere after all the faces are applied, to create a semi-permanent hiding of tags.  Absent additional details regarding how a potential toggle would work in the context of this question, I am unable to comment on that approach (even though I wrote up the solution in the linked thread).  Please give some thought as to what circumstances would trigger toggling on and off, including, but not limited to, how far and wide spread the toggle is -- e.g., just the subtree or the whole buffer in one-fell swoop.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into `org-set-font-lock-defaults`. I was thinking about adding the setting to org-mode's `visibility cycling` to toggle tag hiding on/off...

Comment: Cycling is certainly a possibility, but you'll need to please specify when tags should be visible and when tags should be hidden.  If it is the exact same (in so far as timing) as the linked question, then the job is easier.  If not, then it is still doable, but needs some guidance from you.  I'll check back during the day tomorrow if no one has answered yet.

Comment: Using [this](http://orgmode.org/manual/Global-and-local-cycling.html#Global-and-local-cycling) as a reference, I would probably show/hide tags for subtrees as: FOLDED -> CHILDREN -> SUBTREE -> TAGS and for global cycling: OVERVIEW -> CONTENTS -> SHOW ALL (except tags -> SHOW TAGS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach to hide tags in folded view, and show them in any expanded view.

```
(defun org-toggle-tag-visibility (state)
  "Run in `org-cycle-hook'."
  (message "%s" state)
  (cond
   ;; global cycling
   ((memq state '(overview contents showall))
    (org-map-entries
     (lambda ()
       (let ((tagstring (nth 5 (org-heading-components)))
         start end)
     (when tagstring
       (save-excursion
         (beginning-of-line)
         (re-search-forward tagstring)
         (setq start (match-beginning 0)
           end (match-end 0)))
       (cond
        ((memq state '(overview contents))
         (outline-flag-region start end t))
        (t
         (outline-flag-region start end nil))))))))
   ;; local cycling
   ((memq state '(folded children subtree))
    (save-restriction
      (org-narrow-to-subtree)
      (org-map-entries
       (lambda ()
     (let ((tagstring (nth 5 (org-heading-components)))
           start end)
       (when tagstring
         (save-excursion
           (beginning-of-line)
           (re-search-forward tagstring)
           (setq start (match-beginning 0)
             end (match-end 0)))
         (cond
          ((memq state '(folded children))
           (outline-flag-region start end t))
          (t
           (outline-flag-region start end nil)))))))))))

(add-hook 'org-cycle-hook 'org-toggle-tag-visibility)
```

Comment: Hey John - thanks! It looks like this only works on the current line (where the cursor is). Is there a way to apply this to the buffer globally? So if you have a buffer with say 20 level 1 headers and you shift-tab to fold all of them, then all the tags hide at once?

Comment: Sure. I edited the answer to do that.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm still just able to hide tags one heading at a time... (e.g., global cycling via shift-tab does not hide all tags...?)

Comment: That isn't what I see. When I shift tab and everything collapses, the tags disappear. Subsequent shift-tabs make them reappear.

Comment: Ah okay! So it works great if all headings are top-level (eg * Heading one, * Heading two, etc.). But if you have say a main heading, eg (* Notes) and then sub-headings (** Note one, ** Note two,..., ** Note N) this breaks the script.

Comment: hm. I don't see that either. Maybe I still don't understand what you want. I modified the solution again to hide tags in overview and contents mode with shift-tab, but show them for the final expansion.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks John—this is fantastic!!

Comment: Okay, works great with global cycling! One small bug: if you try to locally cycle a top-level heading with the `TAB` key, all of the tags for that heading and all sub-headings will appear up after it. For example, create a buffer with `* Heading 1` followed by `** Sub-heading 1 :tag1:` and `** Sub-heading 2 :tag2:`. If you place your cursor over `*Heading 1` and hit `TAB`, you'll see `Heading 1...:tag1:...:tag2:`

Comment: it looks like you can add folded as a state to hide those tags. I edited the answer for that too.

Comment: Alright! Global cycling works great. I notice however, that locally cycling any particular heading (`** Sub-heading 2 :tag2:` for example) will also hide/show tags for all other headings in the document. It might be better if global cycling with SHIFT-TAB hides/shows all tags, whereas local cycling with TAB hides/shows only tags for that specific heading..?

Comment: i think the new edit does what you want.